# mysqli_query with a different format

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using a simple php to retrieve data from MYSQL database.

the PHP code is:

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT core_site FROM core_sites");
$coresites = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$coresites[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($coresites);
?>
```

this give me a result of:

```
[{"core_site":"Abbasya"},{"core_site":"Alex Auto"},{"core_site":"Alex Post"},{"core_site":"Banisweif"},{"core_site":"Nasr City"},{"core_site":"Ramsis TE"},{"core_site":"Smart Village"}]
```

I just want to put the data in the results only without column "core_site" to b like:

```
"Abbasya","Alex Auto", "Alex Post", "BaniSweif" .. ETC"
```

what should be my modification? and is there any additional commands required to consider this as Input stream in my android app or the echo does the job?

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the value of the row into the array instead of the row pair key=>value

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $coresites[] = $row['core_site'];
}
```

Comment: many thanks thunder, this works and gave me an output attached with index like that" Array ( [0] => Abbasya [1] => Alex Auto [2] => Alex Post [3] => Banisweif [4] => Nasr City [5] => Ramsis TE [6] => Smart Village )".

Comment: Gald that i could help :)

Comment: hi Thunder, I would be grateful if you supported again :D, I need the output to be only the values without any indexes. "Abbasya", "Alex Auto", "Alex Post", "BaniSweif", "Nasr City" .. etc. thanks again

Comment: Hi Sheriff !! it no suppose to have index can you post a print_r($row['core_site']) ??